# Collect EventLog hourly into a single file

Tags: powershell, reporting, event-log

Is it possible to collect EventLog entries every hour and then save it into a single file in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Get-EventLog`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113314) cmdlet to retrieve the logs, save it to a file using the [`Out-File`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113363) cmdlet and schedule your script using the [`New-ScheduledTask`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=287551) cmdlet.

Comment: @lapsantos Yes, using the `-append` switch.

Comment: Thank you. Will test it.